# Bugfender: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BroadcastChannel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, broadcast-channel, bugfender

I am using bugfender in my vue js application, which works fine in Chrome but doesn't work in my Safari Mac.

Safari Version 15.3 (17612.4.9.1.5)
@bugfender/sdk: 2.2.2

**Error in browser console: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BroadcastChannel**

I did backtrack this issue and it's from bugfender/sdk/lib/index.js

Has anyone face the similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BroadcastChannel` only supports safari from 15.4 and up. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel

if you want use in safari 15.3 down. Use:

```js
import { BroadcastChannel } from 'broadcast-channel'

Object.assign(window, { BroadcastChannel })
```

> you must run this script before all

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade @bugfender/sdk to 2.2.3 and this will work in older safari version.

Answer (score 0):

**@Tachibana Shin,**

*don't add broadcast-channel to window, look at the screen*
[image: don't add broadcast-channel to window]

just add the polyfill
https://github.com/JSmith01/broadcastchannel-polyfill/blob/master/index.js

lazy-load
like this
[image]